# How to solve without the binomial law?

Tags: probability

> A perfect dice is drawn $4$ times.What's the probability to the same number comes out at least $2$ times?

At first, I applied to binomial law.I made all calculations.

I set up a random variable.The possible values for the variable were $0,1,2,3$ and $4$.
My thought was that any number have a probability of $\frac{1}{6}$ to come out.

Then I started to think.In the $4$ launchs two different numbers can come out $2$ times, each one.So my previous thoughts were wrong.

Can you give me an idea on how to solve this problem?

Comment: If you are interested in the probability that there exists a number that comes out at least twice, compute the probability that the four results are different.

Comment: For the first launch there are $6$ possible results, for the second launch there are $5$, and so on until the fourth launch where there are $3$ possible results.So there are $6 \cdot 5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3=360$.Then the total possible cases are $6^4$, and so the probability is $\frac{360}{6^4}$.Is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you find the probability that a $1$ appears at least two times, and similarly a $2$, and a $3$, etc., then you've got the complication that those six events are not mutually exclusive: a $1$ could appear twice **and** a $2$ twice.

So the simpler way is to find the probability that the event you're looking for does **not** occur, i.e. no number appears more than once.

The probability that the second number differs from the first is $\dfrac 5 6$.

The probability that the third number differs from the first two is $\dfrac 4 6$.

The probability that the fourth number differs from the first three is $\dfrac 3 6$.

Multiply those: $\dfrac{5\cdot4\cdot3}{6^3} = \dfrac{5}{18}$.

So what you're looking for is $\dfrac{13}{18}$.

Comment: I chosen this answer, because the calculations are well explain.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

"Alea iacta est !!"

$$P=\frac{6^4-\frac{6!}{2!}}{6^4} \approx 0.722$$

Comment: Now I understood. I've to find the probability of the opposite event.In this case the opposite event is "come out $1$ time on the best way".But in this case don't I have to find the favorable cases to a given number never come out?

Comment: @João,probability=(number of permutations with repetition - number of permutations without repetition)/(number of permutations with repetition)

Comment: Actually $6^3$ is a big enough denominator for the occasion.  (See my answer.)